# Python using type() to deepcopy

Tags: python, deep-copy

I was working on a leetcode question and ran into a problem where I'd have to deepcopy a list. I found a solution that used type() like such:

```
orignallist=[1,2,3]
deepcopylist=type(orignallist)(orignallist)
```

Sure enough, it works and deepcopylist is a deepcopy but how on earth is this working? Python's type() documentation doesn't make any mention of this and I also don't understand how parentheses work with the second (orignallist) added in.

Comment: How did you determine this actually makes a deep copy?

Comment: @ScottHunter because the two have different addresses and also any changes made to deepcopy don't affect the original

Comment: I prefer `type(orignallist)(type(orignallist)(orignallist))` for improved readability ;)

Comment: @ElyMeyers: Different addresses is a product of shallow copy. And since `int`s are immutable, there is no way to mutate a nested element of your `orignallist`, you can only replace/rebind them (which modifies the outer, shallow copied `list`, not the contents of the objects within it, making it impossible to demonstrate any difference between a shallow and deep copy).

Comment: Side-note: For basically all built-in Python sequences (excluding some weirdness with `ctypes` array types and `memoryview`), just slicing the whole thing will achieve the same shallow copy effect (`orignallist[:]` behaves the same as `type(orignallist)(orignallist)` and it's going to be more efficient to boot). And for most built-in mutable collection types, the `.copy()` method will also achieve the desired shallow copy effect more efficiently/directly, so `orignallist.copy()` would also be equivalent and more efficient.

Comment: @ElyMeyers "because the two have different addresses and also any changes made to deepcopy don't affect the original " That is *not* an indication of a deep copy. Your code produces a shallow copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it's not a deep copy. You've made a shallow copy, exactly equivalent to what `list(orignallist)` would produce (it doesn't matter, because all the values contained in your example `list` are immutable types, specifically `int`, but if they weren't, the distinction between deep and shallow copies would be important).

Second, all `type(orignallist)` is doing is extracting the class that the object bound to `orignallist` is an instance of, in this case, `list`. It's runtime determined, so if `orignallist` was actually a `set`, it would get `set`, but right here it's getting `list`. After that, it's nothing special, it's just constructing an instance of whatever `orignallist` is using `orignallist` as the argument to the constructor. If you want to see what it's doing, you can do it piecemeal:

```
>>> orignallist=[1,2,3]
>>> type_of_orignallist = type(orignallist)
>>> type_of_orignallist is list  # It's just another alias to list
True
>>> type_of_orignallist(orignallist)  # Since it's an alias of list, calling it makes a new list
[1, 2, 3]
```

In any event, the correct way to deep copy any object in Python is the `copy.deepcopy` routine:

```
>>> import copy
>>> lst_of_lst = [[]]  # List with mutable element to demonstrate difference between shallow and deep copy
>>> shallow_copy = type(lst_of_lst)(lst_of_lst)  # Or lst_of_lst[:], or lst_of_lst.copy(), or list(lst_of_lst)
>>> deep_copy = copy.deepcopy(lst_of_lst)
>>> lst_of_lst[0].append(1)
>>> lst_of_lst is shallow_copy  # We copied the outer list structure
False
>>> lst_of_lst
[[1]]
>>> shallow_copy  # Oops, shallow, not deep
[[1]]
>>> lst_of_lst[0] is shallow_copy[0]  # Because we didn't copy the inner list
>>> deep_copy  # Does what it says on the tin
[[]]
>>> lst_of_lst is deep_copy
False
>>> lst_of_lst[0] is deep_copy[0]  # Yep, it recursively deepcopied so the inner list differs
False
```

Comment: The "It's just another alias to list" as the type object return of the `type()` function is what makes this answer perfect. I was trying to wrap my head around how the `type` object returned would then produce a list through its call/callable and was struggling to connect those dots.

Comment: @JNevill: Yeah, that's something people coming from languages like Java have to get used to. In many languages, classes and functions are special things, distinct from other objects, you can't use them like other objects. In Python, classes and functions are first-class, they're just another object (it's <s>turtles</s>objects all the way down). Classes themselves are instances of `type` (or a subclass of `type`, when they use metaclasses), that's all (it gets kind of incestuous at the top of the hierarchy, where `type` and `object` implement each other).

Comment: I woudl also add, `copy.deepcopy` is useful to copy arbitrary objects, but for performance reasons, i you know something about the structure of your list, it can be better to do something like `[sublist.copy() for sublist in mylist]` instead of `copy.deepcopy(mylist)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It's an option, but as a rule you want to save that for when profiling saying it's needed (and if it's a hot spot, there's a decent chance you might want to migrate it to `numpy`, if appropriate, and get nested copies cheaply). `copy.deepcopy` is *correct*; best to guarantee correctness by default, and only take maybe-incorrect shortcuts when it's truly needed.

Comment: @ElyMeyers: *Aliasing* would have the same address, but Python doesn't call aliasing shallow copying. That's what `new_lst = old_lst` does (on CPython, it's just copying a pointer to the `list` bound to `old_list` into `new_lst` and incrementing a reference count). Aliasing is the "super-shallow copy". A shallow copy copies the outer structure (the outer `list` itself), but doesn't recurse (it aliases all the things inside the outer structure just like `new_lst = old_lst` does). A deep copy recursively copies until it reaches safe immutable types, it doesn't just copy the uppermost structure.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't understand then how it's a shallowcopy. Maybe my understanding of deep vs shallow copy is incorrect so please correct me if I'm wrong but if it were a shallow copy they'd both have the same address, and any changes I make to the original list would show up in the shallowcopied list. For example: ``` l1=[1,2] l2=l1 ``` both these lists have the same address and if I were to do `l1.append(3)` it would also append 3 to l2. But when doing the `type(l1)(l1)` method, both lists have different addresses and any changes made to one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: @ShadowRanger just saw your new comment. Thank you, now it makes a bit more sense. <3